# How to display footer widgets on a page dependant on a url containing a specific string

Tags: php, wordpress

I have realised that my events page does not display my footer widgets. I had this problem with my woocommerce pages and I fixed it by including the following in the functions.php file:

```
if ( is_woocommerce() )
    include( 'template-parts/footer-menus-widgets.php' );
```

So I need to do something similar. My thinking is to check the url so that if the url contains `/events` then display the footer widget.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Can you try it with `is_page('events')` or `is_archive('events')`?

Comment: @BOZ Sorry for lateness, no it didn't seem either of them worked. I even tried test-event-2 as well instead of events as a test and it did not work. The url looks like so 'https//test.com/events/test-event-2'

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, this code checks if the url contains a string of `/events`. Include this in the functions.php code:

```
 if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/events' )!==false)
    include( 'template-parts/footer-menus-widgets.php' );
```